# ParallaxLayer with multiple images/entities scrolling in Sequential manner

Tags: andengine

Hi I am new to andengine and trying to code a basic sidescroller game using the ParallaxLayer class witch I got from the following example :http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/parallaxlayer-t5390.html I followed the example and it works.

My question is how would I display for example 3 images(Sun_Stage.png, Moon_Stage.png Dark_stage.png) in sequential manner as a scrollable background... First scroll until Sun_stage.png is finnished and then scroll the next stage witch is Moon_Stage.png?

The Player would start in the Sun_Stage while he walks the parallaxlayer would scroll the image.... when the Sun_Stage is finished(reached its end width) then the next Stage Moon_Stage should be visible and scroll?

Hope I make sense? I don't know if there's another way of doing this... I basically just want to code a sidescroller game that's never ending with scrollable background that changes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hoping my answer may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Entity parent = new Entity();                 
        attachChild(parent);              
        Sprite mountainsSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, mountainsTextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                          mountainsSprite.setPosition(0, 0);
                          parent.attachChild(mountainsSprite);

                          Sprite starsSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, starsTextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                          starsSprite.setPosition(mountainsSprite.getX()+ mountainsSprite.getWidth(), 0);
                          parent.attachChild(starsSprite);
                          ParallaxLayer parallaxLayer = new ParallaxLayer(camera, true, 4000);
             backgroundParallax.setParallaxChangePerSecond(8);
            backgroundParallax.setParallaxScrollFactor(1);
            backgroundParallax.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(10, parent, true));
```

Here what i have done is added the required sprites to move in sequence to an entity.Then I made this entity as parallaxEntity to Parallax background

Comment: Thank you for your response, What Class would backgroundParallax be in your example? I tried Implementing it But the parameters are wrong or it states that this line's :      `backgroundParallax.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(10, parent, true));`  should be (float, IShape, boolean)      ? and not (float,entity,coolean)

Comment: then do casting like this  IShape parent = (IShape) new Entity(); or create IShape instead of entity

Comment: When I cast it as a IShape then I get the following error log when running :     `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.andengine.entity.Entity cannot be cast to org.andengine.entity.shape.IShape`

Answer (score 1):

The Rama's answer worked but...
I had to remove last parameter from the `ParallaxEntity`constructor, set position and dimensions of the `Entity` and avoid attaching the `Entity` to the `Scene`.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
Entity parent = new Entity(0, 0, mountainsWidth + starsWidth, height);

// create mountains
Sprite mountainsSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, mountainsTextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
parent.attachChild(mountainsSprite);

// create stars
Sprite starsSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, starsTextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
parent.attachChild(starsSprite);

// create parallax background
backgroundParallax.setParallaxChangePerSecond(8);
backgroundParallax.setParallaxScrollFactor(1);
backgroundParallax.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(10, parent));
```