# AndEngine Parallax with two sprites one after the other

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine, parallax

I am developing a game using andengine in which there is vertical parallax. Currently there is only one image (sprite less than 2048 size) used for parallax but I want multiple images (sprites) in parallax one after the other, how is it possible in a smooth way? Because when i made one image by combining all of them andengine did not load it because the size of image became more than 2048. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the idea described (and answered) here? :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454116/parallaxlayer-with-multiple-images-entities-scrolling-in-sequential-manner

Comment: Yes, i have the same problem, but this answer does not work at all as said in the comments.